# Identity transformation XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an incoming XML document. I just need to modify value of one element example `<ID>` element in this below incoming XML document. I basically need to check for element called `<ID>` if the value is without any hyphen it will take as it is and if the value contains hyphen(-) then i need to take the value before hyphen (-) ex- 4314141
Incoming XML document:

```
<Message>
  <ID>4314141-324234</ID>
  <EMAIL>abc</EMAIL>
</Message>
```

I am using this below XSL to do do this but it is not working as expected.
XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 extension-element-prefixes="dp" 
 exclude-result-prefixes="dp"  >
  <xsl:variable name="uuid" select="dp:variable('var://context/txn/uuid')" />
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/ID">
    <xsl:copy>

            <ID><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ID, ' -')" /></ID>

        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ID"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Let me know how i can do this.

Comment: Two errors here: `match="/ID"` will only match an ID element at the outermost level of the document, and `$ID` refers to a non-existent variable.

Answer (score 1):

> without any hyphen it will take as it is

This will do your identity-copy template.

> if the value contains hyphen(-) then i need to take the value before hyphen (-)

```
<xsl:template match="ID[contains(., '-')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '-')" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Friendly advice: Please be carefull with `/` in your matching patterns.

Comment: Hi  Thanks for your quick response, the solution is not working as expected. I am only getting value of< EMAIL> tag in the out put XML.Can you please check once and let me know.

Comment: @user5458829 - See http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxU. (Note there is no `<xsl:template match="ID"/>` like you have in your original stylesheet.) If your XML input is different (contains default namespaces), please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use this template overriding the identity rule:**

```
  <xsl:template match="ID/text()[contains(., '-')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '-')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

---

**Here is the complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ID/text()[contains(., '-')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '-')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Message>
    <ID>4314141-324234</ID>
    <EMAIL>abc</EMAIL>
</Message>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Message>
   <ID>4314141</ID>
   <EMAIL>abc</EMAIL>
</Message>
```